# How to define global variables in a separate file in C++?

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files

I am writing a school project. In my project there are several functions that work with 20-30 variables. Is there a way I can declare and initialize these global variables in a separate file so my main code remain short and neat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have to use global variables, normally.

```
// Data.h
#ifndef AMIN_PROJECT0_DATA_H_INCLUDED
#define AMIN_PROJECT0_DATA_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

struct Data {
    int age;
    std::string surname;
    std::string firstname;
};

#endif // AMIN_PROJECT0_DATA_H_INCLUDED
```

Now, you can include that header in your source files, and they will be able to use `Data`. You can thus declare functions that take `Data` as a parameter:

```
void checkName(Data const& d) {
    if (d.surname.empty()) { std::cerr << "What, no surname!\n"; }
    if (d.firstname.empty()) { std::cerr << "What, no first name!\n"; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create them as individual global variables, declaring them with `extern` in a header file, and defining each in one C file.

You can also collect related variables in a `struct`, and handle those the same way.

Best, however, is to cut down on the need for global variables. If the variables are related can you just pass `struct`s around? What are they used for?

Comment: Since my project is consisted of a couple of cpp files, if I declare variables as a single struct, won't there be a problem for accessing them in different cpp files?

Comment: No there won't, 20 to 30 variables is way too many. Put them in a struct and pass the struct around.

Comment: That's what `extern` is for.  Use a `typedef` for the the `struct`.  In the header file, use `extern theStructType myStruct`.  In _one_ of the .c files, use `theStructType myStruct`.  But, try to find a better way than global variables.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap these variables in a single struct and pass this struct into these functions. Keeping global variables is generally not a good idea.

Read further: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: Since my project is consisted of a couple of cpp files, if I declare variables as a single struct, won't there be a problem for accessing them in different cpp files?

Comment: Not at all - place the struct in a header, which will be included in all these cpp files. Then pass the data as parameter to all functions you want.